# Why do we need Input Registers, Coil Bits and Input Bits in Modbus

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

In modbus there are 4 object types which are Input registers (R), Holding registers (R/W), Input Bits (R) and Coil Bits (R/W).

What's stopping someone just using holding registers? Why are the other three data types needed?

Comment: I have used devices that they only use the Holding Registers

Comment: @LluisFelisart Do you know why? Seems kind of silly for modbus to create all these object type's when people will only use one holding register with implicit logic that some are read only and that you need to parse through register bit's for bit control. Modbus is an old protocol so I guess back then there was a reason they needed the other object types... or maybe there still is?

Comment: It's a subject I don't care about, it was simply designed that way. What bothers me a bit is that in the manuals of several devices with Modbus communication that I have used they do not use the standard addressing but they indicate an offset and sometimes they do not even indicate that it is an offset in the field of the Holding Register or whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This protocol was originally developed for serial connection devices.
Each of the 4 types can be classified as proprietary equipment.

Input - discrete input (button, limit switch, etc.)

Register input - analog input (temperature, pressure, etc.)

Coil - discrete output (relay, etc.)

Holding register - analogue output (typically 0-10 V, 4-20 mA) (setting speed or temperature, etc.)

Accordingly, we have no right to write something or somehow change the input or input of the register.